# Dynamic Edittext & TextBox

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I have an EditText and a TextView, Now what I want is to fetch the value that is in EditText dynamically (Whatever the user enters in the EditText should be written in TextView), I don't want to use a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a [Key Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnKeyListener%28android.view.View.OnKeyListener%29) for the EditText. Whenever the user types a key, the event listener will get called. You can update the text in the TextView in that key Listener. Something like:

```
editText.setOnKetListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
  Search = search.getText().toString();
  tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
  
  search.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
       public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           tv.setText(search.getText().toString());
    return false;
       }
  });
   
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.papa);
    EditText edtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pa);
    String content = edtext.getText().toString(); 
    text.setText(content);
```